# SyntaxError: Unexpected token at Yarn Run when deploying Laravel/Vue projekt with pipeline yml

Tags: javascript, vue.js, deployment, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to deploy my projekt to a server via bitbucket-pipeline with a .yml script. The projekt has a laravel backend with PHP 7.4 and a Vue Js frontend. The problem occurs when the frontend builds with Yarn Run. The build process is working on my colleagues and my local maschine with the exact same yarn.lock and package.json, but not in the pipeline. Local we also have the same node and yarn/npm version.

This is our pipeline script :

```
    image:
    name: atlassian/default-image:2
definitions:
    steps:
        - step: &laravel-deploy
              name: Laravel Deployment
              caches:
                  - composer
              image: php:7.4.12-fpm
              script:
                  - mkdir -p "$REMOTE_PATH/$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER"
                  - export ROOT_DIR=$(pwd)
                  - mv * $REMOTE_PATH/$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER
                  - cd $REMOTE_PATH/$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER
                  - echo "install dependencies"
                  - echo "install Stuff"
                  - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip && apt-get install -y git && apt install -y openssh-client
                  - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer --version=1.10.13
                  - if [ -z "$YARN_RUN" ]; then
                  - else
                  - apt-get update && apt-get install -y npm
                  - npm config set "@fortawesome:registry" https://npm.fontawesome.com/ && npm config set "//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken" $FA_TOKEN
                  - npm install --global yarn
                  - yarn install
                  - yarn run $YARN_RUN
                  - fi
                  - echo "build application"
                  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
                  - echo $SSH_KEY > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.tmp # note: assumes base64 encoded ssh key without a passphrase
                  - base64 -d ~/.ssh/id_rsa.tmp > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
                  - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
                  - base64 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
                  - eval `ssh-agent -s`
                  - ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
                  - composer install $COMPOSER_OPTIONS
                  - php artisan config:cache
                  - if [ $OP_CAHCE -eq 1 ]; then
                  - php  artisan opcache:clear && php artisan opcache:compile --force
                  - fi
                  - mv -t $ROOT_DIR app artisan bootstrap config  public  resources routes storage vendor database
                  - cd $ROOT_DIR
                  - pipe: atlassian/ssh-run:0.2.3
                    variables:
                        SSH_USER: $SSH_USER
                        SERVER: $SSH_HOST
                        COMMAND: "rm -rf $REMOTE_PATH/$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER"
                  - echo "deploy to server"
                  - pipe: atlassian/rsync-deploy:0.4.0
                    variables:
                        USER: $SSH_USER
                        SERVER: $SSH_HOST
                        REMOTE_PATH: "$REMOTE_PATH/$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER"
                        LOCAL_PATH: "."
                        EXTRA_ARGS: --exclude='.*'
                  - echo "linking resources"
                  - pipe: atlassian/ssh-run:0.2.3
                    variables:
                        SSH_USER: $SSH_USER
                        SERVER: $SSH_HOST
                        COMMAND: "cd ${REMOTE_PATH} && rm -rf current &&  ls -tp | tail -n +6 | xargs rm -rf && ln -s \\$(ls -tr | tail -n1 | xargs -0 realpath) current"


pipelines:
    default:
        - step:
              name: Analyze code
              script:
                  - pipe: sonarsource/sonarcloud-scan:1.1.0
    custom:
        deploy-to-testing:
            - step:
                  <<: *laravel-deploy
                  deployment: testing
    branches:
        staging:
            - step:
                  <<: *laravel-deploy
                  deployment: staging
        master:
            - step:
                  <<: *laravel-deploy
                  deployment: production
```

The following error occurs at the step : - yarn run $YARN_RUN.
and this is part of the error message, its allways SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

```
+ yarn run $YARN_RUN
yarn run v1.22.10
$ cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js -no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
ERROR  Failed to compile with 58 errors8:13:28 AM

 error  in ./resources/assets/js/services/api/user.api.js

Syntax Error: Unexpected token (8:13)

   6 | export default class UserApi {
   7 |   
>  8 |   static url = "/users";
     |              ^
   9 | 
  10 |   /**
  11 |    * Get the user with ID.



 @ ./resources/assets/js/app.js 16:0-46
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

 error  in ./resources/assets/js/services/api/policy.api.js

Syntax Error: Unexpected token (9:13)

   7 |  */
   8 | export default class PolicyApi {
>  9 |   static url = "/policies";
     |              ^
  10 | 
  11 |   /**
  12 |    * Get the policy by given ID.



 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib?{"cacheDirectory":true,"presets":[["env",{"modules":false,"targets":{"browsers":["> 2%"],"uglify":true}}]],"plugins":["transform-object-rest-spread",["transform-runtime",{"polyfill":false,"helpers":false}]]}!./resources/assets/js/pages/Lead/LeadsProvision/components/CommissionPaymentDateComponent/index.js 4:0-63
 @ ./resources/assets/js/pages/Lead/LeadsProvision/components/CommissionPaymentDateComponent/CommissionPaymentDateComponent.vue
 @ ./resources/assets/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

 error  in ./resources/assets/js/services/api/customer.api.js

Syntax Error: Unexpected token (9:15)

   7 |  */
   8 | export default class CustomerApi {
>  9 |     static url = "/customers";
     |                ^
  10 | 
  11 |     /**
  12 |      * Get the customer by given ID.



 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib?{"cacheDirectory":true,"presets":[["env",{"modules":false,"targets":{"browsers":["> 2%"],"uglify":true}}]],"plugins":["transform-object-rest-spread",["transform-runtime",{"polyfill":false,"helpers":false}]]}!./resources/assets/js/pages/Lead/LeadOverview/components/LeadActionComponent/index.js 3:0-67
 @ ./resources/assets/js/pages/Lead/LeadOverview/components/LeadActionComponent/LeadActionComponent.vue
 @ ./resources/assets/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

 error  in ./resources/assets/js/services/api/lead.api.js

Syntax Error: Unexpected token (9:15)

   7 |  */
   8 | export default class LeadApi {
>  9 |     static url = "/leads";
     |                ^
  10 | 
  11 |     /**
  12 |      * Store a new customer for the lead.



 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib?{"cacheDirectory":true,"presets":[["env",{"modules":false,"targets":{"browsers":["> 2%"],"uglify":true}}]],"plugins":["transform-object-rest-spread",["transform-runtime",{"polyfill":false,"helpers":false}]]}!./resources/assets/js/pages/Lead/LeadsProvision/components/PoliceLeadPaymentDateComponent/index.js 5:0-59
 @ ./resources/assets/js/pages/Lead/LeadsProvision/components/PoliceLeadPaymentDateComponent/PoliceLeadPaymentDateComponent.vue
 @ ./resources/assets/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

 error  in ./resources/assets/js/components/SidebarComponent/index.js

Syntax Error: Unexpected token, expected , (10:27)

   8 |   computed: {
   9 |     ...mapState({
> 10 |       sidebarActive: (state: any) => state.sidebar.sidebarActive,
     |                            ^
  11 |     }),
  12 |   },
  13 |   methods: {



 @ ./resources/assets/js/components/SidebarComponent/SidebarComponent.vue 8:21-291
 @ ./resources/assets/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

 error  in ./resources/assets/js/validators/currency-validator.js

Syntax Error: Unexpected token, expected , (11:32)

   9 |  * @returns {boolean}
  10 |  */
> 11 | const currencyValidator = (value: string) => {
     |                                 ^
  12 | 
  13 |   if (value || value === 0) {
  14 |     return (/^([0-9])+(,[0-9]{1,2})?$/).test(value);



 @ ./resources/assets/js/validators/index.js 11:0-53
 @ ./resources/assets/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

 error  in ./resources/assets/js/validators/negative-currency-validator.js

Syntax Error: Unexpected token, expected , (11:40)

   9 |  * @returns {boolean}
  10 |  */
> 11 | const negativeCurrencyValidator = (value: string) => {
     |                                         ^
  12 | 
  13 |   if (value || value === 0) {
  14 |     return (/^-?([.0-9])+(,[0-9]{1,2})?$/).test(value);



 @ ./resources/assets/js/validators/index.js 12:0-70
 @ ./resources/assets/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

 error  in ./resources/assets/js/filters/pretty-bytes-filter.js

Syntax Error: Unexpected token, expected , (11:45)

   9 |  * @returns {string}
  10 |  */
> 11 | export default function prettyBytesFilter(num: number) {
     |                                              ^
  12 |   if (typeof num !== 'number' || Number.isNaN(num)) {
  13 |     throw new TypeError(`Expected a number got ${typeof(num)}`);
  14 |   }



 @ ./resources/assets/js/filters/index.js 5:0-54
 @ ./resources/assets/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

 error  in ./resources/assets/js/store/modules/customer-histories.js

Syntax Error: Unexpected token, expected , (12:30)

  10 |   },
  11 |   mutations: {
> 12 |     setCustomerHistory: (state: any, customerHistory: any) => {
     |                               ^
  13 |       state.customerHistory = customerHistory;
  14 |     },
  15 |     setCustomerHistories: (state: any, customerHistories: any) => {



 @ ./resources/assets/js/store/index.js 9:0-61
 @ ./resources/assets/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

 error  in ./resources/assets/js/validators/insurer-validator.js

Syntax Error: Unexpected token, expected , (12:31)

  10 |  * @returns {boolean}
  11 |  */
> 12 | const insurerValidator = (value: any) => {
     |                                ^
  13 | 
  14 |   if (value) {
  15 |     return value.id !== null && value.id !== '';



 @ ./resources/assets/js/validators/index.js 13:0-51
 @ ./resources/assets/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

 error  in ./resources/assets/js/validators/insurance-type-validator.js

Syntax Error: Unexpected token, expected , (12:35)

  10 |  * @returns {boolean}
  11 |  */
> 12 | const insurerTypeValidator = (value: any) => {
     |                                    ^
  13 | 
  14 |   if (value) {
  15 |     return value.id !== null && value.id !== '';



 @ ./resources/assets/js/validators/index.js 14:0-62
 @ ./resources/assets/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

 error  in ./resources/assets/js/filters/concat-filter.js

Syntax Error: Unexpected token, expected , (12:42)

  10 |  * @returns {string}
  11 |  */
> 12 | export default function concatFilter(value: string, ...args: Array<string>) {
     |                                           ^
  13 |   if (args.length === 0) {
  14 |     return value;
  15 |   }



 @ ./resources/assets/js/filters/index.js 7:0-43
 @ ./resources/assets/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

 error  in ./resources/assets/js/filters/concat-list-filter.js

Syntax Error: Unexpected token, expected , (12:54)

  10 |  * @returns {string}
  11 |  */
> 12 | export default function concatListFilter(listOfStrings: string[], delimiter = ', ') {
     |                                                       ^
  13 |   if (!Array.isArray(listOfStrings) || listOfStrings.length === 0) {
  14 |     return '';
  15 |   }



 @ ./resources/assets/js/filters/index.js 8:0-52
 @ ./resources/assets/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

 error  in ./resources/assets/js/store/modules/user.js

Syntax Error: Unexpected token, expected , (13:20)

  11 |   },
  12 |   mutations: {
> 13 |     SET_USER: (state: any, newUser: any) => {
     |                     ^
  14 |       state.user = newUser;
  15 |     },
  16 |   },



 @ ./resources/assets/js/store/index.js 6:0-34
 @ ./resources/assets/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

 error  in ./resources/assets/js/store/modules/policies.js

Syntax Error: Unexpected token, expected , (13:21)

  11 |   },
  12 |   mutations: {
> 13 |     setPolicy: (state: any, policy: Policy) => {
     |                      ^
  14 |       state.policy = policy;
  15 |     },
  16 |     setEditMode: (state: any, editMode: boolean) => {



 @ ./resources/assets/js/store/index.js 8:0-42
 @ ./resources/assets/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

 error  in ./resources/assets/js/store/modules/customers.js

Syntax Error: Unexpected token, expected , (13:24)

  11 |   getters: {},
  12 |   mutations: {
> 13 |     setCustomers: (state: any, payload: any) => {
     |                         ^
  14 |       state.customers = payload.data.data;
  15 |     },
  16 |     setCustomer: (state: any, payload: any) => {



 @ ./resources/assets/js/store/index.js 7:0-44
 @ ./resources/assets/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

 error  in ./resources/assets/js/validators/zip-validator.js

Syntax Error: Unexpected token, expected , (13:27)

  11 |  * @returns {boolean}
  12 |  */
> 13 | const zipValidator = (value: string) => {
     |                            ^
  14 |   const pattern = XRegExp('^[0-9]{5}$');
  15 |   return pattern.test(value);
  16 | };
```

this is our package.json:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "name": "acm",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "cypress:open": "cypress open",
    "cypress:run": "cypress run",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "docs:generate": "node_modules/.bin/jsdoc resources/assets/js/ -c jsdoc.conf.json -t node_modules/docdash -r -d docs",
    "unit": "cross-env NODE_ENV=testing karma start --code-coverage"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro": "^5.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.6",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons": "^5.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons": "^5.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons": "^5.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "0.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.18",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.9",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "password-generator": "^2.2.0",
    "raven-js": "^3.26.4",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "vee-validate": "2.0.9",
    "vue": "^2.5.13",
    "vue-clickaway": "^2.2.2",
    "vue-context": "^3.2.0",
    "vue-moment": "^3.1.0",
    "vue-multiselect": "2.0.3",
    "vue-perfect-scrollbar": "^0.1.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-simple-spinner": "^1.2.8",
    "vue2-datepicker": "^2.0.4",
    "vue2-filters": "^0.3.0",
    "vuetable-2": "^1.7.2",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1",
    "xregexp": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.25",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.15.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.3",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-flow": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "cypress": "3.1.0",
    "docdash": "^0.4.0",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^13.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype-errors": "^3.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^4.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.5.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.73.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.1.0",
    "jsdoc": "3.5.5",
    "jsdoc-babel": "^0.4.0",
    "karma": "^2.0.2",
    "karma-babel-preprocessor": "^7.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "^0.0.32",
    "karma-webpack": "^3.0.0",
    "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.13",
    "webpack-livereload-plugin": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

we have tried many solutions, such as updating the babel package, editing the babelrc file or trying to install the packages with different package managers. But nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone with the same problem, we found the answer. The problem was the following command :

```
- mv * $REMOTE_PATH/$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER
```

mv moves all files that do not start with a  `.`. Because the babelrc file starts with `.` it was not moved.  Without this file the plugins could not be loaded and the compilation fails. We changed the command to :

```
mv * .babelrc $REMOTE_PATH/$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER
```

and everything worked.